# C# start program with path as argument - path with whitespaces

Tags: c#, process, arguments

First I want to tell you, that I'm still learning english, so I want to apoligize for mistakes.

I have started a programm using Process.Start().
The argument I have passed is a path  to a folder, containing a whitespace.
This whitespace seems to cause an error.
I have tried quotation marks, but this didn't help.

How can I pass this path to the programm, if the path contains a whitespace?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried `Process.Start(@"C:\Some\Path\To\The.exe", "\"some argument containing whitespace\"")`? So basically trying to wrap the arguments with additional quotes.

Comment: Process.Start(compilerPath2 + "\\compiler.exe",  '"' + currentModePath + '"');


@Szabolcs Dézsi:
Thanks, but that didn't help. :/

Comment: That's wrong, if you want to put double quotes around your argument you should use the escaping with \" not a concatenation of a double quotes with your text. This produces an empty string added before and after the argument, in other words, nothing

Comment: Do you mean this?

`'\"' + currentModePath + '\"'`

That didn't work.

Comment: _Process.Start(compilerPath2 + "\\compiler.exe", "\" + currentModePath + "\");_ as explained from the first comment (there are no single quotes only double quotes)

Comment: But this throws an error:
http://www.fotos-hochladen.net/uploads/fffhbm85po0q.png

Double Backslashes will fix this error, but the problem is the same.